# How to overload controller API with different type of `@RequestBody` in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller, overloading

All! I'm currently working on a new project with `SpringBoot` and below is the problem that I've currently encountered. I want to `overload` this controller with different types of parameters. How could I achieve it?

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/register")
    public Status registerConnection(@RequestBody Connection connection) throws Exception 
    {
        xxxx
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/register")
    public Status registerConnections(@RequestBody List<Connection> connections){ 
        xxxx
    }
```

Currently, if I run the program, it reported an error showed below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'connectionController' method 
com.comacnet.controller.ConnectionController#registerConnections(List)
to {POST [/connection/register]}: There is already 'connectionController' bean method
com.comacnet.controller.ConnectionController#registerConnection(Connection) mappe
```

Comment: You should probably use different paths instead.

Comment: use `value = "/registers"` for list registeration like `registerConnections` that you named.

Comment: for both the request body is different so it should work. What issues are you running into can you please put it up in question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use different path for your mappings.

But, still if you wish to do the same below code snippet may help.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/myendpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleMyStringRequestBody(@RequestBody String requestBody) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("This is String Body");
    }

    @PostMapping("/myendpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleMyJsonRequestBody(@RequestBody JsonObject requestBody) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("This is JSON body");
    }
}
```